# Django NameError:  name 'models' is not defined

Tags: django

I have a small application that I wrote in python. Did some research on some web frameworks and decided to use django. I'm reading through the manual and going step by step to learn as much, however I'm stuck on the example given on page 19. When I type the command an I get and error.

```
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone
# ...
class Poll(models.Model):
# ...
    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'models' is not defined
```

I googled "Django NameError:" and didn't find much.

Thanks.

Comment: I fixed the indentation for you. You should indent code properly as I am sure you know indentation is critical in python.  You should also paste the entire file.

Comment: I guess "page 19" doesn't even matter. Sorry about the code. I thought that by adding code in `` it will be properly formatted.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You accidentally missed the whole `import` for `models`.

```
from django.db import models
```

Comment: Thanks Ignacio that took me a step further. However now I'm getting error "IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: And? That's not related to anything in the question.

Comment: @fpena06 The `IndexError` is something completely different that has nothing to do with the code posted here. You should accept this answer (with the checkmark) and ask another one about the IndexError if you still haven't figured that out.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, haha, sorry to ruin your joke, lol :)

Answer (score 1):

Another instance of this error appears when you miss spell stuff :)
like Models.Model instead of models.Model. Quite annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Got this error when accidentally using models.CharField in a form, instead of using forms.CharField